# Postgresql Database Version Control and tracking

Tags: database, git, postgresql, version-control

I'm working on Postgresql and I need to frequently make changes to the data and switch between database versions.

I used to make a virtual machine and use the snapshot feature but it's slow and consumes much storage space.

Is there a way to use git for tracking database changes?

What I tried:
I searched until I found where postgresql stores its database files and created a git repo but without success.

I also found a software dedicated for this purpose but it didn't work either.

Comment: using git and fs would not work (unless you completely stop cluster before `git add`) - postgres keeps pages cached in ram and syncs periodically. you need some versioning software

Comment: I'm curious about your use case. I can understand needing to change the database _schema_ depending on what you're working on (and I do this frequently using database migrations). Why do you need to modify _data_ in this way? What kinds of data changes are you making?

Comment: Use Liquibase or Flyway to version your schema changes. Using `git` will lead to data corruption unless you stop the database before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you must use liquibase

please check [this](https://docs.liquibase.com/start/install/tutorials/postgresql.html)

> Liquibase is an open-source database schema change management solution which enables you to manage revisions of your database changes easily. Liquibase makes it easy for anyone involved in the application release process to:

1. Eliminate errors and delays when releasing databases.
2. Deploy and roll back changes for specific versions without needing to know what
   has already been deployed.
3. Deploy database and application changes
   together so they always stay in sync.